# IIS HTML Parsed By PHP

Tags: php, html, asp.net, iis, ssi

I am on shared hosting using IIS 7.5. I need to be able to parse php code in html files so that I can include my template files. I already have all the html files so I can't go through and change their extensions.

How would I go about this? I think it has to be done in web.config because I don't have access to the IIS manager. I think I also need to find out where the PHP executable file is located?

Thanks

Comment: you can not access php code inside `.html`. But you can access both html and php inside `.php`. What problem is there to change `.html` to `.php`?

Comment: @Anant perhaps that the site is already live and there are linkbacks and I cannot change so many links?

Comment: My knowledge now stop me to say anything on it.Please wait sometime, may be someone else will help you. Good-luck.

Comment: @Kev this question is different because I have stated I am on shared hosting and therefore do NOT know the location of php-cgi.exe